# contentOffset without many items in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am adding a UISearchBar to my UITableView. Like in many apps, the search bar would initially be hidden behind the navigation bar until the user scrolls upwards, revealing it. I use the code bellow to initially hide the search bar which works very well when the table view has enough cells to need scrolling, but does not hide the bar when there are only a few cells in the table view. How can I go about hiding the search bar when there are less than enough cells to cause the table view to scroll.

Current Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if (!self.layedOutHeader) {
        CGPoint contentOffset = self.alertsTableView.contentOffset;

        if (contentOffset.y == -64 || contentOffset.y == 0) {
            contentOffset.y += CGRectGetHeight(self.alertsTableView.tableHeaderView.frame);
            self.alertsTableView.contentOffset = contentOffset;
        }

        self.layedOutHeader = YES;
    }

}
```

Here is an example of how when only a few cells are present, the search bar is not hidden:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `tableFooterView` with the required height to fill the screen when you don't have enough cells.